# How to avoid hard coded string or Access Resource file by enum keyword?

Tags: c#

In Bl i'm using like

```
User.field="Created on".
```

I want to use this by enum.

How to make enum to access resource file by c#.net ?

Or is there any other way ?

Comment: Do you mean Settings.Settings file?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public enum UserField
{
    Createdon = 1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if i have understood you correct. You want to use the enum from resource files

```
string localized = LocalizedString(test.AudioTitle); // this gets the localized result

public enum test // This is your enum
{
    CreatedOn,
    Something,
    SomethingElse
}

public string LocalizedString(test str)  // this method will return the localized value
{
    switch (str)
    {
        case test.AudioTitle:
            return Resources.Audio.AudioTitle; // Audio is a resource file
        case test.AudioUrl:
            return Resources.Audio.AudioUrl;
        case test.LinkTO:
            return Resources.Audio.LinkTo;
        default:
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go through the below link and you can fine some important data related t your question
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Link only answers are not considered acceptable answers on this site. Please at least include a minimum of a summary of the information. Your answer should still add value to the question even if all the links go dead. Your current answer is useless if the link goes dead, we can't even tell what the topic was originally about from the URL.